# IntelliJ bad plugin how to start

Tags: intellij-idea

Hi I have just started using IntelliJ again and have version 9. I just installed the Mercurial plugin and now the ide won't start anymore. 
Has an error of

```
Fatal error initializing class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionManager:
java.lang.VerifyError: class com.dcx.hg.MercurialVcs overrides final method getName.()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I now know that I should be using the plugin **hg4idea**

Is there a way I can remove this plugin so I can start the ide, I am sure there must be..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can answer my own question. 
I am running on a Mac,
the Plugin directory is located in ~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIDEA60/
You can just delete the offending plugin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look in the directory where you installed IntelliJ, you'll see a /plugins directory.  Perhaps if you delete the Mercurial plugin folder you'll be able to restart the UI.  Worth a try.
NOTE: Check [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) for OS/version related plugin path.

Comment: Thanks, 
that is correct. 
Just that I was on a Mac and I couldn't find the plugin directory. I thought it must be in a hidden folder somewhere but it is in ~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIDEA60/

Comment: Based on the OS, the plugin directory location is documented here : https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181

Answer (score 18):

I am running on a Mac, the Plugin directory is located in `~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIDEA60/` You can just delete the offending plugin. Note, depending on your edition of the IDE, the directory may be different. For example, `IdeaIC2016.3`

Comment: The directory has been changed to `~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea*` for more recent versions.

Answer (score 12):

Version 11 for Windows stores plugins also in `c:\Users\<username>\.IntelliJIdea11\config\plugins\` so delete plugins from that location as suggested by @duffymo.

Comment: 12 is the same (just with a 12). If it is an error from restarting during a plugin upgrade, then delete the action script and zip file found in c:\users\<username>\.IntellijIdea12\system\plugins\

Answer (score 9):

Ran into the same problem with another plugin. The solution was to remove the offending plugin folder *or* `jar` from the **Plugins** folder - see the exact location below for your OS.

The locations of the user plugins folder for different platforms are listed at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs:

### OSX

Configuration:

```
~/Library/Preferences/<PRODUCT><VERSION>
# e.g.:
~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea14
```

Caches:

```
~/Library/Caches/<PRODUCT><VERSION>
```

**Plugins**:

```
~/Library/Application Support/<PRODUCT><VERSION>
```

Logs:

```
~/Library/Logs/<PRODUCT><VERSION>
```

### Linux/Unix

```
~/.<PRODUCT><VERSION>
```

### Windows

Windows Vista, 7, 8:

```
<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>
```

Windows XP:

```
<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Documents and Settings\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>
```

Answer (score 5):

Version 15 on Ubuntu:

```
cd ~/.IntelliJIdea15/config/plugins
rm -r <offending_plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the plugin. In my MacOS, the path to the plugins folder is:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/<your version>/plugins
```

Comment: There is no plugins directory at that location in my machine. I'm using the toolbox, maybe that changes the location?

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ IDEA 2022 Community Edition the directory seems to be

```
c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdealC2022.2\plugins\
```