# Intellij IDEA 15.04 startup error on update on OSX El Capitan

Tags: intellij-idea, osx-elcapitan, intellij-plugin

I just updated to IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4 and now get this startup error:

```
Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.text.StringsKt.isEmpty(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.StateStorageManagerImpl.addMacro(StateStorageManagerImpl.kt:95)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ApplicationStoreImpl.setPath(ApplicationStoreImpl.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$11.run(ApplicationImpl.java:477)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:455)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:447)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:60)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:361)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I found this [article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/02/intellij-idea-15-0-4-update-is-out/) (see the comments section) and tried following the advice there and disabling the `Kotlin` plugin - I just tried entering the line:

> Kotlin

in the `config/disabled_plugins.txt` file, but that didn't work - not sure i have the plugin name right. I also just tried nuking the `Kotlin` directly under the IDEA `plugins` directory but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running OpenJDK?  That may have something to do with it.

Comment: No, its oracle. I also have a working version of community edition post-upgrade, so I suspect it is something ultimate edition related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by taking the nuclear option and re-installing the IDE. Now works with a fresh 15.0.4 download even without the plugin disabled. The re-install is actually pretty painless. All my settings and config are still there. Only thing I had to do was add my license key again.

Answer (score 1):

I've just reviewed my [plugins folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782425/intellij-bad-plugin-how-to-start) and realized that my `disabled_plugins.txt` has disabled Kotlin like

> org.jetbrains.kotlin

Try to disable Kotlin also this way.

Comment: still no luck, though thanks for the plugin name in case that works for anybody else.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see 'Welcome to IntelliJ IDEA' dialogue?

Here is ability to disable some plugins before IDE launch 
[image]

Comment: No, Unfortunately not :(